# Why Powershell output all items in collection ignorig IF statement?

Tags: windows, powershell

This code supposed to output only macaddress of active connection, yet it output all macaddresses of all PhysicalAdapters

```
# Assign info on Network Connections selected fileds to collection
$q = Get-CIMInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter | Select-Object NetConnectionStatus, PhysicalAdapter, MACAddress
 
# Find mac address of active connection
foreach ($i in $q) {IF ($q.NetConnectionStatus -eq 2) {Write-Host $i.MacAddress}}
```

In output I recieve all macaddresses of all physical adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on your `if` condition, `$q` is the *collection* not the *item* (`$i`):

```
IF ($q.NetConnectionStatus -eq 2)
```

Since `-eq` can act as a filter when the left-hand side of the operation, as long as there is at least one element in `$q.NetConnectionStatus` equal to `2`, the condition will be `$true` hence all items are being outputted to the console.

Try this simple example to understand what is happening:

```
$collection = 0..10 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        NetConnectionStatus = $_
        MACAddress = Get-Random
    }
}
foreach($item in $collection) {
    if($collection.NetConnectionStatus -eq 2) {
        $item.MACAddress
    }
}
```

This will output 11 random numbers to your console. The right filtering condition on above example should have been:

```
if($item.NetConnectionStatus -eq 2) {
```

Comment: ok. I understand, that in this case even if there is one statement which match IF statement, it will be TRUE for all collection. Yet, I do not understand how to check every item in collection.

Comment: In Santiago's example above the bottom ForEach loop in the Use: 
if($item.MACAddress.NetConnectionStatus -eq 2)

Comment: @RetiredGeek thank you, thought the answer was explanatory